# terminal cannot download from https://pypi.python.org/simple/sh/

Tags: python, linux, pypi, buildozer

I am trying to install a package, buildozer, related to my python on Linux.

During the installation, it stucks on this line: 
    "Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/sh/"

even I wait for many hours, but nothing happens. The point is that I can open this website using the browser easily.

So what is the problem? What should I do?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. Please edit your question : The used command is missing. Is it pip? Or pip3?

Comment: @KnudLarsen     sudo python setup.py install        is the command which should be run in the buildozer folder